# calling php function from submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to pass the value of input field `address` to php. So that when i click on submit button it will be store in php.

```
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="submit" name="go" method="post">
<?php
    if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    call();
    }else{
    echo "Error";
    }
    }
    function call(){
    echo "hi";
    print(document.address.value);
    }
?>
```

However when i click on button it response nothing.

Comment: this is java script function "document.address.value"; you have to write it in script tag

Comment: Use html form... read about it

Comment: learn as to how HTML & Javascript are different , You need to use ajax to do the above thing

Comment: Use form post and get value of Address using $_POST['address']. As @saty said document.address.value is JS function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing PHP and JavaScript. If you want a pure PHP solution you could do something like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     echo $address;
}
?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <input type="submit" name="go" method="post">
</form>
```

With PHP once the form is submitted you can access form values with `$_POST` so use `$_POST['address']` instead of `document.address.value`

Answer (score 3):

what you intend to do can be done as below method.

```
<form method="post" >

<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="submit" name="go">

</form>



<?php
    if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    call();
    }else{
    echo "Error";
    }
    }
    function call(){
    echo "hi";
    echo $_POST['address'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Loenix, yup. That was an alternative but removed that and edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,this is working fine as per your requirement:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
Address: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="call" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
    call();
    }
?>
<?php
function call() {
 $address= $_POST['name'];
echo "Address:".$address;
exit;
}
```

**Output:-**

For output  [Click here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b1Pfr7)

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="submit" name="go" method="post">
<?php
    if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    call();
    }else{
    echo "Error";
    }

    function call(){
    echo "hi";
    echo $_POST['address'];
    }
?>
```